# Debugging APS package in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, saas, zend-debugger

I am new to APS technology (for SaaS). I know that Eclipse has a plugin for creating and debugging APS. I've installed it. But at the moment I can't debug "Helloworld" APS package which contains PHP scripts. I need to run APS player for that purpose. I've added PDT and Zend debugger support in Eclipse. The problem is linked with Web server from WAMP and Zend debugger. I've added different combinations of settings in php.ini after adding ZendDebugger.dll. But phpinfo shows that ZendDebugger is not activated. Where dummy.php must be put when we deal with APS? So, I need a working combination of Eclipse, APS plugin, web server and Zend Debugger. In fact, I can use any application,debugger stuff, not just pure Eclipse. I use Windows 7, 64bit. Which file should i choose from here http://downloads.zend.com/pdt/ ? Should I use Zend Server in order to have an easy support of Zend debugger? Will xdebug work instead of zend debugger for APS debugging?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test any APS package you must integrate it in the Parallels Panel, even a simple hello world package, because the php scripts are actually aps types that need to be provisioned first. good luck